# Finding a point given a graph equation and a tangent line

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

how do I find a point given the graph of the equation (that is $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$) where the tangent plane is parallel to the equation $x+y-z = 0$ ?

what I did was take the gradients of both equation, and equate to the corresponding variables (equate the x value of gradient 1 and gradient 2, etc.). I ended up with a set of points, are they correct tho? Please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Have you written down the equations correctly? There is no tangent plane to $x^2-y^2-z^2 = 1$ that is parallel to the given plane.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to put it in the question but an alternate ending to the question was "justify if there are none". I didn't think there would be none that's why I omitted that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a point on an implicit surface, the gradient vector and normal vector at that point are parallel. The gradient of $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$ is $(2x,-2y,-2z)$, and we want it to be parallel to the normal of $x+y-z=0$ which is $(1,1,-1)$:
$$(2x,-2y,-2z)=k(1,1,-1)$$
$$2x=k,-2y=k,-2z=-k$$
$$x=-y=z$$
The desired points may then be computed by substituting the last equality into the implicit equation and simplifying, so we get $x^2=-1$ which is impossible. Thus no points of the graph have tangent plane parallel to $x+y-z=0$.